# What does . /opt/pat/staging/config/VARIABLES>>/dev/null do?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

What does this command mean in a shell script? What is the functionality of writing this command in the shell script??

```
. /opt/pat/staging/config/VARIABLES>>/dev/null
```

Comment: If this were broken down into smaller questions ("what does `. somescript` do?" and "what does `>>/dev/null` mean?"), this might have made it easier to find an individual answer for each.

Answer (score 1):

Sources the file in order to load the variables into your current environment and sends only stdout (not stderr) to `/dev/null` (black hole, if you will).

To send both stdout and stderr you would do `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Answer (score 0):

Runs the script in the context of the current shell and sends all its output to the null device to avoid having it in the current standard output.